# Get text from row column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am only getting back the entire row as a object, what I am trying to get is the second column's row data.

```
    $('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    var nTr   = this;
    var i     = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);
    var aPos  = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(aPos[0]);

    console.log(aData[0]);
    if (i == -1) {
        $(this).addClass('row_selected');
        var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen(nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr, 1), 'details');
        $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
        anOpen.push(nTr);
    }
    else {
        $(this).removeClass('row_selected');
        $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp(function () {
            oTable.fnClose(nTr);
            anOpen.splice(i, 1);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#table_id tbody').on('click', 'tr', function (e) {
    var secondColumn = this.cells[1]; // returns HTMLTableCellElement
```

Now you can work with `secondColumn` to get all the data you need, such as `secondColumn.innerHTML`. If you need to work with the cell in jQuery, just use

```
    var secondColumn = $(this.cells[1]);
```

instead.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Property 'cells' of object #<HTMLTableRowElement> is not a function

Comment: Works, Ill have to parse the html out of the string but everything is good. I get this <td class>infoinfo</td>

Comment: What you get is the HTMLTableCellElement, if you need to convert it to jQuery, you can use `$(this.cells[1])`, i'll put that in the answer as well.

Comment: With the $(this.cells[1]); I get this [td, context: td, constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", jquery: "1.8.2"…]
0: td
context: td
length: 1
__proto__: Object[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

    var cell = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[2];
    var cellText = cell.childNodes[0];
    if(cellText.data == '02/06/2010') {
        // do something with cell
    }
}
```

Try it here http://jsfiddle.net/ANsUq/